# Have to reset wireless frequently on iPad / Macs connected to Cisco WRV200

Tags: mac-osx, router, ipad, wifi

I have a Cisco WRV200 set up in our small office. The wireless signal works great for PCs, but I have found that Macs and iPads have to frequently reset the connection. It will be working for about 10 minutes, then stop. To fix it, I just turn off Airport and turn it on again. On an iPad, I have to go into settings, shut the wireless off, and then turn it on again.

The router is broadcasting mixed B/G on channel 6. Security is WPA-PSK2.

Anybody out there had similar issues with their router? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This has been an issue for some time with MAC... (truth is its not just MAC ... but anyhow...)

Generally WPA has 2 modes:

Enterprise mode (which generally utilizes a Radius server for authentication of its users 
& 
Personal mode (which uses the capabilities of Temporal Key Integrity (TKIP) for WPA).

try changing this over to TKIP as the protocol and you should find it is a much nicer user experience.

we did this for a number of macbooks some time ago and it worked well. 
had to find the post from macrumors on it to remember what we did

Give that a shot...

Hope it helps